# Symfony, routing.yml is not working

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes

I have a project in sympfony.
Im trying to add a new page, and i have done usual steps, but nothing seems to work.
I have added the following to src/ITWB/FrontBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
itwb_front_abc:
pattern: /abcCenter
defaults: { _controller: ITWBFrontBundle:Footer:abcCenter }
```

In my src/ITWB/FrontBundle/Controller/FooterController.php i have added this:

```
public function abcCenterAction() { 
return $this->render('ITWBFrontBundle::test.html.twig');
}
```

But it's not working.
I have tried putting and "echo" inside the action, and it isnt displaying, so, the problem is in the routing, domain.com/abcCenter its not being recognized. I have also tried with other names and it's the same.

What can i do ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care of indent, like Wouter J says.

You can access abcCenter via domain.com/app_dev.php/abcCenter (not domain.com/abcCenter) if your website is running local, otherwise you have to clear cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

[How to deploy a Symfony2 application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html).

Comment: Was a cache problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the indent the options. Indenting is a really important aspect of Yaml:

```
itwb_front_abc:
    pattern: /abcCenter
    defaults: { _controller: ITWBFrontBundle:Footer:abcCenter }
```

Comment: Note that indentation is done with 2 or 4 spaces in Yaml format, you can't use tabulations.

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would look: in app/config/routing.yml, do you have a reference to your bundle's routing.yml?

The app/config/routing.yml file should contain a couple of lines something like this:

```
front_bundle:
    resource: "@FrontBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Of course maybe you've done this already as part of the "usual steps" you mention?